# ggplot: colour of line segments according to variable value, like scale_color_gradient2

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, segment, scale-color-manual

I have a df "test_data", which contains values of the recent year ("recent"), the year before ("before") and the difference between these two ("delta").

in the given ggplot, the points are coloured according to the value of "delta" with scale_color_gradient2.

Line segments are drawn to link the points with the dashed line.

I was only able to colour all negative deltas in one colour (red) and all positive deltas in one colour (green), which does not reflect delta.

Is there a way to colour the line segments according to delta, like with scale_color_gradient2 for the points?

reproducable code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

test_data<-structure(list(recent = c(65.2997185753145, 59.7196309660111,
                                     69.6283618162288, 72.8567667757411, 75.5042106908949, 65.9349599258225, 
                                     63.821946931775, 84.5492780693781, 70.1954593423904, 68.7330477506608, 
                                     74.7016955531504, 71.0329793728603, 90.8076584032142, 72.1556242719194),
                          before = c(68.1971224074475, 53.6815581922758, 67.3141074572482,
                                     70.8701488937935, 73.9713609414785, 63.2296191743796, 56.6943338152896, 
                                     81.7035240884654, 77.3175553964688, 69.7366705789213, 78.2019304405689, 
                                     71.6072916545225, 86.8455685297511, 75.7745946931338),
                          delta = c(-2.89740383213299, 6.03807277373529, 2.31425435898061, 
                                    1.98661788194759, 1.5328497494164, 2.7053407514429, 7.1276131164854, 
                                    2.8457539809127, -7.1220960540784, -1.0036228282605, -3.5002348874185, 
                                    -0.574312281662188, 3.96208987346309, -3.6189704212144)),
                     
                     row.names = c(NA,-14L),
                     class = "data.frame")
               
  
                                                                                                          

test_data<-test_data%>%
  mutate(x1_neg=case_when(delta<0 ~ before),
         y1_neg=case_when(delta<0 ~ recent),
         x2_neg=case_when(delta<0 ~ recent),
         y2_neg=case_when(delta<0 ~ recent))%>%
  mutate(x1_pos=case_when(delta>0 ~ before),
         y1_pos=case_when(delta>0 ~ recent),
         x2_pos=case_when(delta>0 ~ before),
         y2_pos=case_when(delta>0 ~ before))


plt<-ggplot(test_data, aes(x=before,y=recent))+
  geom_abline(slope=1,linetype = "dashed")+
  geom_segment(aes(x = x1_neg, y = y1_neg, xend = x2_neg, yend = y2_neg),
               colour="#E24C3B",
               size=1.3)+
  geom_segment(aes(x = x1_pos, y = y1_pos, xend = x2_pos, yend = y2_pos),
               colour="#ADCA1E",
               size=1.3)+
  geom_point(aes(color=delta),size=3)+
  scale_color_gradient2(high = "#ADCA1E",mid="#6ECFF6",low = "#E24C3B")+
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#FFFFFF"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#FFFFFF"),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.grid = element_line(colour = "#D2D0CF"),
        legend.justification = "bottom")+
  ylab("recent")+
  xlab("before")+
  coord_fixed()

x11(5,5)

plt
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Map `delta` on `color` in `geom_segment` too?

Comment: yes you're right! never thought it was that easy. so it works, the result is exactly, what I want, but what I don't understand is how the colours are "synchronized" between the segment, mapped on color, and the points, coloured by scale_colour_gradient2()

Answer (score 0):

as @stefan mentioned, "delta" can be mapped on color in geom_segment. so if the plot definition is adapted like this, it works:

```
plt<-ggplot(test_data, aes(x=before,y=recent))+
  geom_abline(slope=1,linetype = "dashed")+
  geom_segment(aes(x = x1_neg, y = y1_neg, xend = x2_neg, yend = y2_neg, colour=delta),
               size=1.3)+
  geom_segment(aes(x = x1_pos, y = y1_pos, xend = x2_pos, yend = y2_pos, colour=delta),
               size=1.3)+
  geom_point(aes(color=delta),size=3)+
  scale_color_gradient2(high = "#ADCA1E",mid="#6ECFF6",low = "#E24C3B")+
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#FFFFFF"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#FFFFFF"),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.grid = element_line(colour = "#D2D0CF"),
        legend.justification = "bottom")+
  ylab("recent")+
  xlab("before")+
  coord_fixed()

x11(5,5)

plt
```

[image: with coloured segments]

Comment: you could make it even easier by using just one `geom_segment`, i.e. there is no need for `_neg` and `_pos`, just do `mutate(x1 = before, y1 = recent, x2 = if_else(delta < 0, recent, before), y2 = if_else(delta < 0, recent, before))`. For your question concerning the "sync" between the points and the segment. For both you map the same `delta` on the `color` aes. Hence both get assigned the same colour via `scale_color_gradient2`, i.e. the scale is not connected to a geom, it's connected to the aesthetic.